# Give a matrix $A$ find a symmetry matrix $X$,such $A=X^3-10X^7$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:**

> let
>   $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
> 3&-6&0\\
> -6&0&-6\\
> 0&-6&-3
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>   Find a symmetric matrix $X$,such that $$A=X^3-10X^7$$

I think this problem have more methods,but I can't

Answer (score 4):

The matrix $A$ is symmetric and real hence diagonalizable. That is, there is some orthogonal $U$ and diagonal $\Lambda$ such that $U^TAU = \Lambda$. A little work shows that we may take $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(9,0,-9)$.

Now let $y_1 $ solve $9 = x^3-10x^7$ (for example, $y_1 = -1$ is a solution). Let
$Y=\operatorname{diag}(y_1,0,-y_1)$. Then we see that
$Y^3-10 Y^7 = \Lambda$. Hence $X=U Y U^T$ solves $A=X^3-10 X^7$.

If we note that $Y = {y_1 \over 9} \Lambda$, we see that $X = {y_1 \over 9} A$.

Note that there are many solutions, this is one particularly simple one that only involves eigenvalue computation and noticing that $-1$  solves $9 = x^3-10x^7$.